# How to get an object from another object if I do not know key name

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

in firebase i want to extract data but it returns object inside another object `Object {
 "-LJFXZDI-O-qR572deOs": Object {
   "city": "almaty",
    "dob": "1995-08-06",
    "gender": "male",
    "height": "190",
    "userId": "LS1pYNjiIjRpSNV1xfXqngKAKjz2",
    "username": "aaaa",
     "weight": "80",
  },
 }`

i want to get inner object `"city": "almaty",
    "dob": "1995-08-06",
    "gender": "male",
    "height": "190",
    "userId": "LS1pYNjiIjRpSNV1xfXqngKAKjz2",
    "username": "aaaa",
     "weight": "80",`

but i do know this key  "-LJFXZDI-O-qR572deOs" what should i do?

Comment: Use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). It will return an array of all the values. If your object only has the one key it will be an array with one item, which is the object you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you access the key without knowing the key, using Object.keys:

```js
var obj = {
  "-LJFXZDI-O-qR572deOs": {
    "city": "almaty",
    "dob": "1995-08-06",
    "gender": "male",
    "height": "190",
    "userId": "LS1pYNjiIjRpSNV1xfXqngKAKjz2",
    "username": "aaaa",
    "weight": "80",
  },
}

keys = Object.keys(obj); // all keys of the outer object
myKey = keys[0]; // the unknown key of the inner object
innerObject = obj[myKey];
city = innerObject.city;

console.log(city);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const obj = {
  "-LJFXZDI-O-qR572deOs": {
    "city": "almaty",
    "dob": "1995-08-06",
    "gender": "male",
    "height": "190",
    "userId": "LS1pYNjiIjRpSNV1xfXqngKAKjz2",
    "username": "aaaa",
    "weight": "80",
  }
};
const key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
const city = obj[key].city;

console.log(key);
console.log(city);
```